# delete directories based on a text file

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

Let's say a user has 50 directories within their home.  We want to delete only certain directories. If we create a file with the specific directories to delete, can a script be used to delete based on the contents of the file? We don't want to have to delete these one by one, and we can't do it by date or other pattern.

Comment: What is the attempt you made?

Comment: Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: I understand, I am new to this and am not looking for anything extensive, was just inquiring if it was possible and a possible command. I was hoping it was a simple situation that many familiar with scripting would know off the top of their head without any real effort on anyone else's part.

Comment: @Matt - if your question isn't about programming, then it's off-topic for StackOverflow. Perhaps it would be better suited to http://SuperUser.com/ or [Unix & Linux](http://Unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible of course. Here is an example for reading a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
done < "$1"
```

`IFS=''` prevents leading or trailing whitespaces from being trimmed

`-r` prevents backslashes to be interpreted

`|| [[ -n $line ]]` prevents your last line of being ignored if it isn't ending with `\n`

As for the deleting you can substitute the echo with whatever you like.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you. The explanation was very helpful as well.  Instead of echo I used: rm -R $line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on unix, and your text file is called "dirs" with 1 directory per line all you have to do is:

```
cat dirs | xargs rm -rf {\;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs -r rm -rf <dirs.txt
```

Where dirs.txt contains the names of your directories.